# Javascript Adding pixels to current position of div

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the right arrow key is pressed I would like to increment the left position of a `div` by `10px` using the `style` property. Here is my script and what I've tried so far:

```js
document.onkeydown = KeyPressed;

function KeyPressed(k) {
 
    var LeftBtn = 37;
    var RightBtn = 39;
    var UpBtn = 38;
    var DownBtn = 40;
  
    if (k.keyCode == RightBtn) {
        document.getElementById("test").style.left = document.getElementById("test").style.left + 10px;
    }

}
```

```css
#test {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: I am not sure I get your problem. Do you want to manipulate the element's position from right? Cos you write that you want to add 10px to right, but your style fixes the element to left and your script is reading left property of the element. There are some issues in your code, for sure, but I do not get your goal, so please, clarify first.

Answer (score 3):

The `style` property of a DOM element is essentially a dictionary with **string** key-value pairs. It expects a CSS key, and a proper string value.

Your current code comes out as `left: 10px10px` and that doesn't make much sense for CSS.

In order for this to work, you'd have to regard the `px`.

```js
document.onkeydown = KeyPressed;

function KeyPressed(k) {

  var LeftBtn = 37;
  var RightBtn = 39;
  var UpBtn = 38;
  var DownBtn = 40;

  if (k.keyCode == RightBtn) {
    var moveEl = document.getElementById("test"),
      currLeft = parseInt(moveEl.style.left || 0);
    moveEl.style.left = (currLeft + 10) + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
#test {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Further reading and examples - [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `px` from `10`.

```
if (k.keyCode == RightBtn) {
    document.getElementById("test").style.left = document.getElementById("test").style.left + 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

```
document.onkeydown = KeyPressed;

function KeyPressed(k) {

    var LeftBtn = 37;
    var RightBtn = 39;
    var UpBtn = 38;
    var DownBtn = 40;

    if(k.keyCode == RightBtn) {
        document.getElementById("test").style.left = parseInt(document.getElementById("test").style.left || 0) + 10 + 'px';
     }

}
```